# What is this plant? Is it ground cover?

Tags: identification, ground-cover

[image]
[image]

Green fast growing both short and tall growth. Did not have it previous years but taking
over an area that had ground cover.

Is this a fast growing weed or a ground cover or some sort of climbing ivy?

New York update Ductchess county NY
Thanks so much 
Nancy

Answer (score 5):

What you have is either Virginia creeper (*Parthenocissus quinquefolia*) or woodbine (*Parthenocissus vitacea*) judging by  the shape of its leaves. Both grow as a vine but it may take a while longer to become noticeable. Both are in the same genus as Boston ivy which is not a true ivy.

Woodbine https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocissus_vitacea

Virginia creeper https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocissus_quinquefolia

Comment: Note that this is very different to the woodbine that Shakespeare refers to and UK usage which refers to *Lonicera periclymenum* (more commonly  referred to as european or common honeysuckle)

Comment: *Parthenocissus* can make quite good ground cover but as they are self-clingers they will climb when they encounter anything vertical.

Comment: Once established this plant will cover houses, cars and slow moving animals.  It is subject to grape beetles and turns a nice red in the fall.  Not recommended for a small area

Comment: kevinsky - I wish that was true in one of my homes (different province in Canada) as it was slow to get established. Even then, the growth was slow. I wanted it to cover a very ugly wire mesh fence. In all the time we lived there, it didn't go more than a couple of yards on either side. I guess it depends on whether it knows you want it or not, and with growth being inverse proportion to your fondness of it!